# select2 differentiating free text responses (tags: true)

Tags: javascript, user-interface, select, jquery-select2

I'm using select2 in my app with the [setting](https://select2.org/tagging) `tags: true`

In the image below, the word *cells* is a new option (i.e. not part of the pre-populated set of select options).

[image]

I'm wondering how people are implementing a better way to differentiating that the *cells* option being presented in the select is a new option instead of a current option?

I've thought about doing it by using custom functions for the options [`createTag`](https://select2.org/tagging#tag-properties) and [`templateResult`](https://select2.org/dropdown#templating)

```
function templateResult(el) {
    return 'newTag' in el ? el.text + ' (new tag)' : el.text;
}

function createTag(params) {
    var term = $.trim(params.term);

    if (term === '') {
      return null;
    }

    return {
      id: term,
      text: term,
      newTag: true // add additional parameters
    }
}
```

to get something like:

[image]

Has anyone come up with something better?

Answer (score 1):

It's enough to change a bit your **createTag**:

```js
$(".js-example-tags").select2({
    tags: true,
    createTag: function (params) {
        var term = $.trim(params.term);

        if (term === '') {
            return null;
        }
        return {
            id: term,
            text: term + ' (new tag)',  // add text....
            newTag: true // add additional parameters
        }
    }
}).on('change', function(e) {
    $(this).next('.select2-container').find('li:contains(" (new tag)")').text(function(idx, txt) {
        return txt.replace(' (new tag)', '');
    })
});
```

```css
.js-example-tags {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>


<select class="form-control js-example-tags" multiple>
    <option selected="selected">orange</option>
    <option>white</option>
    <option>purple</option>
</select>
```

Comment: the issue with this solution is that when the option is selected it has the appended ' (new tag)' along with it.

Comment: @Constantino Snippet updated. Let me know if now it works. Thanks